# how to add the plugin fluent-plugin-opensearch to docker

Tags: docker, fluentd, opensearch

I'm trying to send logs from `fluentd` (installed using docker) to opensearch.

In configuration file, there's `@type opensearch` that uses the plugin `fluent-plugin-opensearch` which I installed locally as a Ruby gem.

I get the following error:

```
2022-04-22 15:47:10 +0000 [error]: config error file="/fluentd/etc/fluentd.conf" error_class=Fluent::NotFoundPluginError error="Unknown output plugin 'opensearch'. Run 'gem search -rd fluent-plugin' to find plugins"
```

As a solution, I found out that I need to add the plugin to the `fluentd` docker container, but I couldn't find a way to do that.

Any way to add the plugin to docker or an alternative to this solution would be appreciated.

Comment: You might need to create a custom Dockerfile with all the dependencies and then build that. Example: https://github.com/CloudWebManage/cwm-worker-logger/blob/main/Dockerfile

Comment: @Azeem I created the custom dockerfile and made it into an image. But I'm not sure how it can be used. since the plugin needs to be in the same container as fluentd. and we can't have multiple images in the same container

Comment: Good. What do you mean by multiple images? The plugin would be part of the newly created image with fluentd as its base image. Could you please share more details about how you're doing it?

Comment: You should be using the newly created image. Please add your Dockerfile, the commands that you used to build it, and run it in your question.

Comment: @Azeem Since I couldn't figure that out, I'm using docker compose and following this documentation : https://docs.fluentd.org/container-deployment/docker-compose  Maybe this is what you meant as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comments already gave a hint, you will need to build your own Docker image. Depending on the infrastructure you have available, you can either build the image, store it in some registry and then use it in your compose file, or build it on the machine that you use docker on.

**The Dockerfile**

Common to both approaches is that you'll need a Dockerfile. I am using Calyptias Docker image as a base, but you can use whatever fluentd image you like to. My docker file looks as follows:

```
FROM ghcr.io/calyptia/fluentd:v1.14.6-debian-1.0

USER root

RUN gem install fluent-plugin-opensearch
RUN fluent-gem install fluent-plugin-rewrite-tag-filter fluent-plugin-multi-format-parser

USER fluent
ENTRYPOINT ["tini",  "--", "/bin/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["fluentd"]
```

As you can see it installs a few more plugins, but the first `RUN` line is the important one for you.

**Option 1**

If you have a container registry available, you can build the image and push it there, either using a CI/CD pipeline or simply locally. Then you can reference this custom image instead of whatever other fluentd image you're using today as such:

```
fluentd:
    image: registry.your-domain.xyz/public-projects/fluentd-opensearch:<tag|latest>
    container_name: fluentd
    ports:
      - ...
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ...
```

Adjust the config to your needs.

**Option 2**

You can also have `docker-compose` build the container locally for you. For this, create a directory `fluentd` in the same folder where you store your `docker-compose.yml` and place the `Dockerfile` there.

```
fluentd:
        build: ./fluentd
        container_name: fluentd
        ports:
          - ...
        restart: unless-stopped
        volumes:
          - ...
```

Instead of referencing the image from some registry, you can reference a local build directory. This should get you started.

Comment: Thank you for the answer it is very clear and helpful, this worked out well for me.

Comment: Hi @issrae - glad you liked the answer and it worked out for you. If your question has been answered to your satisfaction, please accept the answer such that the question is properly marked as solved. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work